# How to get items from column of v-select in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have the column of v-select in v-data-table, how can i get selected items? v-model not working because it binds to all v-select

[image]

```
<template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
    <v-select
    :items="allProjects"

    outlined
    class="mt-2"
    ></v-select>
</template>
```

Comment: just don't share one reference - use multiple - either by something like `v-model="selected[item.uniqueIdentifier]"` or item.selected

Comment: @Estradiaz it's work if i use the `v-model="selected[tags.indexOf(item)]` , but when i delete item, the index is changing and i get wrong selection, how can i solve it?